# Kings chosen by Allah

Tags: prophets

Hello my name is Hussein and I’m from Tanzania. My question is how many people did Allah make be king? And who were they? I know Dhul Qarnain was a king though he wasn’t a prophet and he was made to be a king by Allah. Apart from Dhul Qarnain who else did Allah choose as kings?

Comment: Saul (Talut), David and Solomon عليه السلام